# Change URL pattern of rest API

Tags: java, json, rest

```
@Path("/ftocservice")
public class RestService {

  @Path("{f}")
  @GET
  @Produces("application/json")

  public Response convertFtoCfromInput(@PathParam("f") float f)
      throws Exception {

    DbCon db = new DbCon();
    ArrayList<Student> students = db.getStudentList();
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(students);

    String result = jsonArray.toString();

    return Response.status(200).entity(result).build();
  }

}
```

I'm using above source code to **generate** **rest API** and user is requesting through the API as **follows**.

```
http://localhost:8080/RestExample/RestService/ftocservice/23
```

I need to change the request URL as follows.

```
http://localhost:8080/RestExample/RestService/ftocservice?f=23
```

Please help to change the source code to change request URL as given. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to use `@QueryParam` instead:

```
@Path("/ftocservice")
public class RestService {


  @GET
  @Produces("application/json")
  public Response convertFtoCfromInput(@QueryParam("f") float f)
        throws Exception {

    DbCon db = new DbCon();
    ArrayList<Student> students = db.getStudentList();
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(students);

    String result = jsonArray.toString();

    return Response.status(200).entity(result).build();
  }
}
```

See this [link](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e2225) for more info on parameter types in JAX-RS.

This [tutorial](https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jax-rs-queryparam-example/) by [Mkyong.com](http://Mkyong.com) is also quite nice.

Comment: It's hard to tell what's wrong without code or logs. Remember to remove the `@Path` and `@PathParam` annotation and, depending on your setup, you might need to redeploy the code.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. I used it in a wrong way. Thank you very much.

Comment: Sure, no problem! Good luck!

Comment: Oh, and don't forget to mark the answer as correct ;)

Answer (score 2):

use `@QueryParam` instead of `@PathParam`

Comment: I don't think there's such a thing as `@RequestParameter`

Comment: sorry.. mistaken its @QueryParam